# Datatables remove row from another table

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have two data tables.  One is the "Selection Table", which has a column with a checkbox.  When this checkbox is checked, the row data is added to the "Preview Table".  When the checkbox is unchecked, it should remove the row from the Preview table.

My problem is that the unchecking from the box actually gets rid of "all" the rows in the Preview Table.

```
$('#selectNodesTable tbody').on('click', 'tr #nodeToAdd', function () {
        var row = ($(this)).closest('tr');
        var rowObj = nodeTable.row(row).data();
        console.log(rowObj);

        if (($(this)).is(':checked')) {
            nodePreviewTable.row.add(rowObj);
            nodePreviewTable.draw();
        } else {
            // THE BELOW STATEMENT DELETES ALL ROWS FROM THE PREVIEW TABLE
            nodePreviewTable.row().remove(rowObj);
            nodePreviewTable.draw();
        }
    });
```

Comment: seeing an ID as target selector of the click event is very suspicious since ID's can't be repeated in a page. Also highly doubtful that the objects are references to each other in both tables. Suggest you create a demo in jsfiddle.net or plnkr.co . Can use cdn resources for datatables js and css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not totally clear what you want. But I assume you want to move rows back and forth two [**jQuery dataTables**](https://www.datatables.net) instances, based on click on checkboxes? If you have two tables, `#selectNodesTable` and `#previewNodesTable`, you can move a row when a checkbox is checked *from* `#selectNodesTable` *to* `#previewNodesTable` this way :

```
$('#selectNodesTable').on('click', 'input[type=checkbox]', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
        tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        row = selectNodesTable.row(tr);
        rowData = [];
        tr.find('td').each(function(i, td) {
            rowData.push($(td).html());
        });    
        row.remove().draw();
        previewNodesTable.row.add(rowData).draw();
    }
});
```

Notice the regeneration of `rowData`. This is to ensure that you pass a checkbox that actually *is* checked. `row.data()` will only return the cached row content, i.e the unchecked checkbox. If you also want to do the opposit, as I assume :

```
$('#previewNodesTable').on('click', 'input[type=checkbox]', function() {
    if ($(this).not(':checked')) {
        $(this).removeAttr('checked', 'checked');
        tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        row = previewNodesTable.row(tr);
        rowData = [];
        tr.find('td').each(function(i, td) {
            rowData.push($(td).html());
        });    
        row.remove().draw();
        selectNodesTable.row.add(rowData).draw();
    }
});
```

see demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/zwLm043e/**

The above could of course easily be generalised into a single function doing both actions depending on the state of the clicked checkbox.